# Why doesn't select() react on received messages?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to abort sending UDP data to specific hosts when I receive data back from any of them.
 
So far what I've tried is creating a thread inside other function that sends data. 
Thread is supposed to be checking for incoming data on socket descriptors for maximum of 100 secs.
 However select() function only waits for timeout and doesn't respond when data is received. Sockets are already created in calling function, here I'm only passing file descriptors. 
Also this is modified code snippet from Beej's Guide to Network Programming.

```
void *bot_listen(void *arg){

    printf("Thread starting\n");
    size_socks *sock_size=(size_socks*)arg;
    int  n, rv;
    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval tv;

    thr_running=1;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    for(int i=0;i<sock_size->size;i++) {
        FD_SET(sock_size->sockets[i], &readfds);
    }

    n = sock_size->size + 1;

    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    tv.tv_sec = 100;
    rv = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (rv == -1) {
        perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
    } else if (rv == 0) {
        printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 100 seconds.\n");
    } else {
        bot_recv_message=1;
    }
    thr_running=0;
}
void send_dgrams(int num_ip, struct message ip_port_pairs, char *message){
        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
        struct sockaddr_in *dest;
        char udp_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        char udp_port[22];
        char *p;
        int *sockfd, time_elapsed=0;
        size_socks ss;

        printf("Message, beginning of send_dgrams: %s\n", message);
        pthread_t listen_thread;

        sockfd = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_ip);
        dest = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)*num_ip);
        p=&(ip_port_pairs.command);
        p++;

        for(int i =0; i<num_ip;i++) {

            memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

            hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
            hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
            strcpy(udp_ip, p);
            p+=INET_ADDRSTRLEN;
            strcpy(udp_port,p);
            p+=22;

            getaddrinfo(udp_ip, udp_port, &hints, &res);
            sockfd[i] = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

            dest[i].sin_family = res->ai_family;
            dest[i].sin_port = ((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_port;
            dest[i].sin_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
            memset(dest[i].sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(dest[i].sin_zero));
        }

        ss.size=num_ip;
        ss.sockets=sockfd;
        pthread_create(&listen_thread, NULL, bot_listen, (void*)&ss);
        while(bot_recv_message==0 && time_elapsed<100) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num_ip; i++) {
                printf("Sending this message: %s to socket %d\n", message, sockfd[i]);
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(dest[i].sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                printf("Sending to this address: %s\n", str);
                printf("Sending to this port: %d\n", ntohs(dest[i].sin_port));
                printf("Did bot receive message? :%d\n", bot_recv_message);
                sendto(sockfd[i], message, strlen(message) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dest[i], sizeof(dest[i]));
            }
            sleep(1);
            time_elapsed+=1;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<num_ip;i++){
            close(sockfd[i]);
        }
        bot_recv_message=0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to simultaneously listen for incoming messaged while sending them

Comment: You write "on received message". Did you receive any message? How did you checked this? Please include the code that [a] creates and binds the receive socket(s), [b] sends the message that should be received.

Comment: @pytness *"you should know that UDP is only used to send data, not to recieve it"*.  Utter nonsense.  If you can't receive UDP data, what's the point of sending it?  UDP is a connectionless protocol that operates in a fire-and-forget manner.  There is no reliability built in like TCP, so reliability needs to be implemented at the application layer, but you most certainly can receive UDP packets.

Comment: @harper Included code that binds sockets. Any message received from host aborts sending

Comment: Your code doesn't bind the sockets to any port. So they can't receive data, `select()` times out.

Comment: @harper So select() requires socket to be bound and recvfrom() doesn't? Because recvfrom() works without binding the socket. And if that's so, is there an alternative solution to using select()?

Comment: @user3104311 `recvfrom` won't work without binding either.  You **must** bind to a port locally to receive anything.

Comment: @dbush you're right, i got it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the problem:

```
n = sock_size->size + 1;
...
rv = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

Value of the 1st parameter of `select()` won't be big enough.

Man page of the `select()` says the following about the 1st parameter:

> `nfds` should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of
>      the three sets, plus 1.  The indicated file descriptors in each set
>      are checked, up to this limit (but see BUGS).

So try something like this:

```
int max_fd = -1;

for(int i=0;i<sock_size->size;i++) {
    FD_SET(sock_size->sockets[i], &readfds);
    if (sock_size->sockets[i] > max_fd)
         max_fd = sock_size->sockets[i]; 
}
...
rv = select(max_fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```